# Parse HTML table data to JSON and save to text file in Python 2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract the data on the crime rate across states from
    this webpage, link to web page
    http://www.disastercenter.com/crime/uscrime.htm

I am able to get this into text file. But I would like to get the
    response in Json format. How can I do this in python.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib        
import re     

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
link = "http://www.disastercenter.com/crime/uscrime.htm"    
f = urllib.urlopen(link)    
myfile = f.read()    
soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile)    
soup1=soup.find('table', width="100%")    
soup3=str(soup1)    
result = re.sub("<.*?>", "", soup3)    
print(result)    
output=open("output.txt","w")    
output.write(result)    
output.close()
```

Comment: Your result is a long way from being json, what are you expecting as output?

Comment: Put the data in a useful Python data structure made of lists/dicts/strs/numbers, then use the json module.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am expecting table contents to be in form of JSON in an text file or even table data into csv would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will get the data from the two tables and output all of it as a json formatted string.

**Working Example (Python 2.7.9):**

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import re as regular_expression
import json

page = requests.get("http://www.disastercenter.com/crime/uscrime.htm")
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

tables = [tree.xpath('//table/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/center/font/table/tbody'),
          tree.xpath('//table/tbody/tr[5]/td/center/center/font/table/tbody')]

tabs = []

for table in tables:
    tab = []
    for row in table:
        for col in row:
            var = col.text_content()
            var = var.strip().replace(" ", "")
            var = var.split('\n')
            if regular_expression.match('^\d{4}$', var[0].strip()):
                tab_row = {}
                tab_row["Year"] = var[0].strip()
                tab_row["Population"] = var[1].strip()
                tab_row["Total"] = var[2].strip()
                tab_row["Violent"] = var[3].strip()
                tab_row["Property"] = var[4].strip()
                tab_row["Murder"] = var[5].strip()
                tab_row["Forcible_Rape"] = var[6].strip()
                tab_row["Robbery"] = var[7].strip()
                tab_row["Aggravated_Assault"] = var[8].strip()
                tab_row["Burglary"] = var[9].strip()
                tab_row["Larceny_Theft"] = var[10].strip()
                tab_row["Vehicle_Theft"] = var[11].strip()
                tab.append(tab_row)
    tabs.append(tab)

json_data = json.dumps(tabs)

output = open("output.txt", "w")
output.write(json_data)
output.close()
```

Comment: at the end of my webpage there are links to various states by name and by year. If I want even these as links in my JSON file how do I extract that?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want, if you can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) modules. The data structure presented here is very simple, adjust this to your needs.

First, get a response from your requested URL and parse the result into an HTML tree:

```
import requests        
from lxml import etree
import json

response = requests.get("http://www.disastercenter.com/crime/uscrime.htm")
tree = etree.HTML(response.text)
```

Assuming you want to extract both tables, create this XPath and unpack the results. `totals` is "Number of Crimes" and `rates` is "Rate of Crime per 100,000 People":

```
xpath = './/table[@width="100%"][@style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"]//tbody'
totals, rates = tree.findall(xpath)
```

Extract the raw data (`td.find('./')` means first child item, whatever tag it has) and clean the strings (`r''` raw strings are needed for Python 2.x):

```
raw_data = []
for tbody in totals, rates:
    rows = []
    for tr in tbody.getchildren():
        row = []
        for td in tr.getchildren():
            child = td.find('./')
            if child is not None and child.tag != 'br':
                row.append(child.text.strip(r'\xa0').strip(r'\n').strip())
            else:
                row.append('')
        rows.append(row)
    raw_data.append(rows)
```

Zip together the table headers in the first two rows, then delete the redundant rows, seen as the 11th & 12th steps in slice notation:

```
data = {}
data['tags'] = [tag0 + tag1 for tag0, tag1 in zip(raw_data[0][0], raw_data[0][1])]

for raw in raw_data:
    del raw[::12]
    del raw[::11]
```

Store the rest of the raw data and create a JSON file (*optional:*  eliminate whitespace with `separators=(',', ':')`):

```
data['totals'], data['rates'] = raw_data[0], raw_data[1]
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, separators=(',', ':'))
```